# Running time of counting and radix sort

Tags: sorting, time, radix-sort

I know that counting and radix sorts are generally considered to run in O(n) time, and I believe I understand why. I'm being asked in an assignment, however, to explain why these sorts may not necessarily sort a list of distinct, positive integers in O(n) time. I can't come up with any reason.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

To say that counting or radix sort is O(n) is actually not correct.

[**Counting sort**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) is O(n+k) where k is the maximum value of any element in the array.

The reason is the you have to step through the entire list to populate the counts (O(n)), then step through the counts (O(k)).

[**Radix sort**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) is O(mn) where m is the maximum number of digits of a number.

The reason is that you have to step through the array once for each digit (O(n) m times).